# Can an Italian taxpayer living in the UK receive a NINo and open an ISA?

Tags: united-kingdom, isa, italy

I live, work, and pay my taxes in the UK. My wife is:

- an Italian citizen
- living in the UK
- working remotely for an Italian company, and
- paying her taxes in Italy.

Can she request a NINO and open an ISA? I have maxed out my ISA allowance and would find it useful to start using hers, if she is entitled to have one.

Comment: Are you sure she should be paying taxes in Italy rather than the UK? https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/double-taxation/index_en.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes if she is a UK resident.

https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts

> Who can open an ISA
> You must be:
>
> - 16 or over for a cash ISA
> - 18 or over for a stocks and shares or innovative finance ISA
> - 18 or over but under 40 for a Lifetime ISA
> - **resident in the UK**

Rules for UK residence:

https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence

> You’re automatically resident if either:
>
> - you spent 183 or more days in the UK in the tax year